# android back key on browser does not launch previous activity

Tags: android, browser, android-activity, android-intent

I'm expecting quite a strange behavior in a tiny app I'm currently working on.

The app consists of two activities. From the first activity I'm launching the webbbrowser via an intent. When I press the back key in the browser it returns to the SECOND activity even if I manually closed the app previously before launching.

**1) First Activity**

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mWebShopURL));
startActivity(intent);
```

**First Activity launches second activity like this**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("product", mProduct);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

**2) Second Activity -> first activity**

```
onBackPressed();
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Where did you place your "First Activity launches second activity like this"-code in the first activity?

Comment: Thx for your reply. It's inside a View.OnClickListener and gets launched when the user clicks a simple button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the second activity to complete and go away when the user taps on the simple "back button" you refer to in your comment, then don't call `onBackPressed()`. Please just call `finish()`. That will make the second activity go away and return the user to the first activity.

Your problem is that you've never removed the second activity from the stack, which is why returning from the browser shows that activity.

Comment: David, thanks for your reply. Just calling finish() didn't help either. I'm with you it's a stack problem. If I call finish() or I call the first activity from an intent like @Abhi suggests the first activity should be the first in the stack. So I'm quite at a loss.

Comment: I coded a dummy app with my code and it's actually working (with onBackPressed()) fine.. :/

Comment: Well, finish() is the correct thing to do, not simulate the back button. In any case I don't see what could be causing this. Can you post more code? Show us how you get to the webbrowser. Show us your other lifecycle methods like onCreate(), onResume(), etc. or just post all your code somewhere and put a link to it here.

Comment: David, I'd like to post the code or put a link to it here but it's actually client work so I'm not allowed to. Is there any possibility to mail you a download link? Your help is highly appreciated as I'm not able to solve it on my own. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure. You'll find my email address in my profile. Mail me a link and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks David for looking at my code! A simple "break" inside a switch clause was missing. That's why I started the browser and the second activity at the same time. Oh damn. I mark your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct You are overriding `onBackPressed()` in your second Activity.Dont do that put `onBackPressed()` code in comments and try. Hope it will help :)

Comment: No, I'm not overriding it. I just call onBackPressed() when the user taps on a simple "back button". Anyways, thx for your reply.

Comment: You have seperate back button to go back to First activity? if yes call intent to start first activity

Comment: Yes, that's a more elegant solution but it doesn't solve my problem unfortunately;)